# Different ending(s) to Constantine the movie?

Tags: dc, constantine-2005, constantine

When the movie *Constantine* came out I thought I'd seen a version where in the end Gabriel got her wings back, emerging from the pool while smiling. As if the whole plot was to get John to the 'good' side. The only endings I found from a bought DVD or clips are; John quitting smoking by chewing gum and Chas becoming an angel.

I checked clips, scripts, message boards, still nothing...

A friend also mentioned seeing the ending I did. Are we delusional or is this ending somewhere out there?

Comment: It doesn't answer anything definitively but when I saw the movie back when it first hit theaters, I saw the gum chewing version.

Comment: Chas dies? In the comics, he's the only friend Constantine has who can survive the experience!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To my best knowledge there are only two versions of endings:

1. Constantine on the rooftop chewing gum instead of smoking

2. Constantine visiting Chas' grave, when he witnesses his friend resurrected and turned into an angel

You guys probably mistook Chas for Gabriel.